# Average value of a column in Spark

Tags: apache-spark, average, aggregate-functions, rdd

I am new to `Spark`. I have below RDD

```
Mathew,science,45

Mathew,history,55

Mark,maths,23

Mark,science,76
```

I want to find out average marks of each subject. Please help me.

Comment: first make it key,value pair with subject as key and marks as value and then use reducebykey to get the sum and devide by each subject counts thats all

Answer (score 0):

for test purpose I am creating rdd as below

```
val rdd = sc.parallelize(Seq(
  ("Mathew,science,45"),
  ("Mathew,history,55"),
  ("Mark,maths,23"),
  ("Mark,science,76")
))
```

> > I want to find out average marks of each subject

Now *make it key,value pair with subject as key and marks as value with extra 1 for count and then use reducebykey to get the sum and devide by each subject counts*

```
rdd.map(line => {
  val splitted = line.split(",")
  (splitted(1), (splitted(2).toInt, 1))
})
  .reduceByKey{(x, y) => (x._1 + y._1, x._2 +y._2)}
  .map(kv => (kv._1, kv._2._1.toDouble / kv._2._2.toInt))
```

this should give you

```
(maths,23.0)
(history,55.0)
(science,60.5)
```

Comment: If the answer helped you @iamdeep then you should consider accepting the answer to let others know that its solved :)